# Вставка или обновление по условию, (сложно)?

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Есть 4 ячейки, нужно вставить значение в пустую, т.е. если ячейка `A` пустая, то вставляй в нее, допустим 10, далее, если ячейка `A` занята, то проверить ячейку `B`, если она пуста, то вставляй в нее 10, иначе, проверяй далее ячейку `C`, если она пуста, вставляй в нее 10, и так же само с ячейкой `D`, если все заняты, то вообще вставляй в новую запись в ячейку `A` значение 10. Мой запрос выглядит так:

```
mysql> UPDATE `mytable` SET `A`=10,`B`=10,`C`=10,`D`=10 WHERE `A` IS NULL OR `B` IS NULL OR `C` IS NULL OR `D` IS NULL LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1 Changed: 1 Warnings: 0
```

увы, это вставляет во все ячейки значение 10. Может возможно как-то прерывать запрос когда в какое-либо одно и только одно поле было вставлено значение? Конечно очень хотелось бы еще и if affected=0 INSERT INTO `mytable`(`A`) VALUES(10) зачудить, но моим возможностям и познаниям пока это тяжело, надеюсь на помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Трудно представить в какой ситуации такое алгоритм может понадобиться. Вероятнее всего вы неправильно спроектировали структуру БД.

Решением в вашей ситуации может стать хранимая процедура. Синтаксис процедур дает возможность использовать условия, с помощью которых можно запрограммировать любую логику изменения данных.

Comment: смотри, есть турнир, из 4 мест, если какое-то место не занято, то вставляй в этот турнир команду, если все заняты, то создавай новый турнир, ситуация?

Comment: Сделал выборку последнего ряда таблицы, если есть свободная ячейка в выбранном ряде - заполняешь ее, если свободных ячеек нет, создаешь новый ряд и пишешь в его первую ячейку. Не могу понять - **что здесь сложного** и причем тут структура БД? И самое главное - зачем здесь городить процедуру, SQL процедуры это нелепое убожество, написанное на недоязыке, в данном случае использование оных не только неоправдано, но и сделает код не читаемым, слабо расширяемым и т.д., при том, что, еще раз повторюсь - задача элементарна

Comment: Если-же принципиально вынести всю логику в одно обращение к БД, вот тогда вы действительно на пути в пропасть (читай в пекло, в ад, в гости к Люциферу, как кому угодно).

PS: SQL процедуры полезная и удобная вещь, но **однозначно** не в этом случае

PPS: надеюсь авторы ответа и вопроса не думаю что SQL процедура чем-то лучше, чем серверный код, если же я ошибаюсь, тогда, естественно, дискуссия бессмысленна.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, с помощью "нелепого убожества" написанного на "недоязыке" можно ускорить сложную обработку данных за счет того, что будет обработан только один запрос от клиента. Остальные отработают в процедуре на сервере без возврата результата. Также это избавляет от каши из SQL-запросов и, например, PHP-кода.

В этом случае, да, можно обойтись одним SELECT-ом и, по условию, UPDATE либо INSERT. Только вот конечная цель задачи стала понятна когда откомментил топикстартер. Поэтому, в ответе, я и написал "Решением **может стать** хранимая процедура".

Comment: Также, не забывай о том, что кроме веба, где между клиентом и БД есть прослойка (php, ruby, pyton, etc.), еще бывают GUI-интерфейсы, которые работают с базой напрямую. А там, иногда, без использования логики на стороне БД вообще все плохо.

Это все к тому, что у каждого инструмента есть своу круг решаемых ним задач. И некорректоно называть что-то "недоязыком", когда сам вероятно "недопонял" или "недоучил".

Comment: @KiTE - смею Вас разочеровать, все я понял и все я доучил. Добавление любой SQL процедуры, как минимум, усложняет программисту жизнь т.к. SQL процедуры хранятся на стороне БД, добавим к этому еще то, что, нередко в SQL процедуре  без бутылки не разобраться и получим мягко говоря не самую радужную картину.

"каши из SQL-запросов" ога, ORM? не, не слышал.

"еще бывают GUI-интерфейсы" - кэп бессилен

"которые работают с базой напрямую" - ога и написаны на SQL xD (иначе каГбы есть яп)

По поводу "ускорения" либо "упрощения" за счет процедуры - это не тот случай ( что было понятно сразу )

Comment: я сделал двумя запросами, на сколько это выгодно или "профессионально"... я просто боюсь судить, в моем случае это не ноухау, все равно у меня уже штук 30 запросов, потихоньку оптимизирую. (первый масштабный prject, допустимо?)

Comment: @Zowie не надо распространять тот факт, что вы не осилили язык запросов или ещё чего. У всего есть своё применение.